# Docker engine swarm mode | Alternative of "extra_hosts" used in compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

In docker compose file i was able to declare a domain & IP like below -

```
extra_hosts:
  - "mshost:10.4.12.31"
  - "mongodb DEV-MONGODB:10.250.12.35"
```

I want to know the alternative to this while using below command in docker engine swarm mode .

```
"docker service create ...."
```

Comment: There is no alternative. It is not supported yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not supported in docker 1.12  but is supported in docker 1.13 ([#28031](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/28031)). You can archive the same thing as extra_hosts with `--host`

```
docker service create --host "mshost:10.4.12.31" --host "mongodb:10.250.12.35" --host "DEV-MONGODB:10.250.12.35"
```

[docs](https://github.com/yongtang/docker/blob/ea9a23ccdbd3a861e4cfa3441482b448fd1c17a5/docs/reference/commandline/service_create.md)